# Link not working in table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm making this site for my friends mom and for some reason my links aren't working in my table, I have reason to believe that it has something to do with the CSS, also I've never had this problem before so I'm not fully sure how to fix it. The code works in Chrome but not Firefox also to clarify, I can't click on the link, it turns it blue and underlines it but I just generally can't click on it at all.

HTML

```
<nav>
<table id="nav_table">          
<tr>
<td class="nav_border">
<a href="www.google.com"><p class="nav_options">Home</p></a>
</td>
<td class="nav_border">
<p class="nav_options">Restaurants</p>
</td>
<td class="nav_border">
<p class="nav_options">Near you</p>
</td>
<td class="nav_border">
<p class="nav_options">Order Here!</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
nav{
position: relative;
top: 50px;
}

#nav_table{
position: relative;
top: 60px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
 border-spacing: 5px 0px;
border-collapse: ;
height: 0px;
}

.nav_border{
text-align: center;
border: 2px solid black;
padding: 10px;
width: 120px;
height: 0px;

-webkit-box-shadow: rgb(,,) 0px 0px 0px ;
-moz-box-shadow: rgb(,,) 0px 0px 0px ;
box-shadow: rgb(,,) 0px 0px 0px ;

background:-webkit-radial-gradient(center,circle,red 0%, orange 50%);
background:-moz-radial-gradient(center,circle,red 0%, orange 50%);
background:radial-gradient(center,circle,red 0%, orange 50%);

-webkit-border-radius: 25px;
-moz-border-radius: 25px;
border-radius: 25px;
}

.nav_options{
font-size: 20px;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Now as I said before I've never had this problem, I've tried googling it and it said it had to do with changing the parent element width and height to percentage instead of pixels but I don't think it applied to what I'm trying to get done.

Comment: This is kinda bad. You don't have *any* links in that code. That's why they don't work.

Comment: Like John has pointed out, you have no links? Your opening tags are paragraphs, not anchors.

Comment: There I fixed it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not correct. If you want link with text you should first try this

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">link text</a>  

<nav>
<table id="nav_table">          
<tr>
<td class="nav_border">
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" p class="nav_options">Home</p></a>
</td>
<td class="nav_border">
<p class="nav_options">Restaurants</p>
</td>
<td class="nav_border">
<p class="nav_options">Near you</p>
</td>
<td class="nav_border">
<p class="nav_options">Order Here!</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</nav>
```

Comment: There Fixed sorry kind of forgot to throw that in while I was copying. I guess when I was editing I didn't realize I copied the code without the links, but here I added one and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to put 'http://' in front of your urls, so the browser knows it is an absolute URL.

e.g. href="http://www.google.com"

Without, the browser thinks the URL is relative so it's taking you to the wrong page.

It's also better backwards compatibility to put your anchor tags inside your paragraph tags.

```
<p class="nav_options"><a href="http://www.google.com">Home</a></p>
```

Comment: So I did what you said and the problem isn't that it's sending me to the wrong place, the problem is that I can't click on it in general, it does the default thing with links by turning it blue and underlining it but I can't click it and it doesn't send me anywhere. also links work outside the <td> but anywhere inside, links won't work.

Comment: The 'Home' text link works for me in firefox here: http://jsfiddle.net/6zc37gdh/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your cod isn`t correct , you must add < a > < / a > tag in to  < p > < / p >

if you want clickable cell use it CSS for a tag :

```
a.Click { 

width:100%;
height:100%;
display:block;
text-align:center

}
```